# CSS Flex (Grow/Shrink) to shift responsive item alignment?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly use the flex-grow and flex-shrink utilities in Bootstrap (4.4)

I have a navigation container containing 3 `<li>` elements, using a mobile-first method; i'd like to accomplish the following:

**Mobile Layout** (sm) (All `<li>` elements equally spaced (width 33.3%)

```
   Element 1                                Element 2                                           Element 3
```

**Larger Devices** (md+) (2 `<li>` elements left aligned, 3rd `<li>` right aligned)

```
   Element 1   Element 2                                                                        Element 3
```

**Code:**

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-fill">
            <ul class="nav list-unstyled list-inline d-flex flex-fill">
                    <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                               Element 1
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item  list-inline-item  flex-fill">
                               Element 2
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item  list-inline-item  flex-fill">
                                Element 3
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Using flex-fill gets the mobile layout working. I can't get flex-md-{grow|shrink} to shrink element 1 and grow element 2 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-fill">
  <ul class="nav list-unstyled list-inline d-flex flex-fill justify-content-around justify-content-md-start">
    <li class="nav-item list-inline-item ">
      Element 1
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item  list-inline-item">
      Element 2
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item  list-inline-item ml-md-auto">
      Element 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```